# No data with consecutive AutoFilter statements on different columns in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofilter

I have a large spreadsheet of data that I am trying to filter using autofilter.  I have two autofilter statements that, when I run them at the same time, return no data (which I know is a mistake).  But, when I run them separately they work fine.  I am not sure what is causing this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Each "rng" is the specific column that is being filtered.

```
    rng3.AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "CMS Part D (CY " & Year(Date) & ")", "Commercial", "State Medicaid"), Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues

    rng4.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="No"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a variable "rng" that is the entire table you are trying to filter. I will assume for this example that "rng3" is column A and "rng4" is column B.

```
Sub Filter()
Dim rng as Range

Set rng  = Range("A:B")
rng.Autofilter 1, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "CMS Part D (CY " & Year(Date) & ")", "Commercial", "State Medicaid"), Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues
rng.Autofilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="No"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is because your Field attribute is 1 for each statement even though your ranges are different columns. For example, if rng3 is Column A, then the field attribute should be 1. If rng4 is Column B, then the field attribute should be 2. Something like this....

```
        Dim rng3 As Range
        Dim rng4 As Range
        Set rng3 = Range("A:A")
        Set rng4 = Range("B:B")

        rng3.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("CMS Part D (CY " & Year(Date) & ")", _
            "Commercial", "State Medicaid"), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
        rng4.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="No"
```